# How can I possibly implement a VueJS app to Odoo?

Tags: vue.js, odoo

I have to integrate a VueJS app in Odoo. I don't exactly know how I can achieve that?

I found this https://www.odooinvue.org/ (not my app, but an example app) . Still no idea on how can I implement odoo in Vue. Login gives me a Failed to Login error message in this example app.

Any idea how to implement odoo in vue??

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of that project. Its really impossible to answer you without knowing what steps you have taken to setup the project, but for that error, make sure of the following:

1. The Odoo server is up and running in the backend and you can login.
2. When you login with the front-end Vue app, you are using credentials that you know are working.
3. If that fails, open the dev console of your browser and check the network log. Make sure that the authentication request is returning status code 200.

I know others that are using the project just fine without any issue, so I am going to assume that you need some technical help. Perhaps hire a software developer to assist you.

Comment: I will be updating OdooInVue for Vue3 and Odoo14, soon.

Comment: @micheal-m do you use primevue and pinia ? just curious lol ^^

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `odooinvue` works fine. Read carefully the instructions, in development it shows how to start a traefik docker container in order to serve both odoo and Vue.js.
Note: If I am not wrong, the purpose is to use odooinvue as a pure frontend, so it's not really an integration, basically you build vuejs (`quasar`, specifically) apps with odoo used as a pure backend.

See also [this answer, by odooinvue's author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63199705/2783654)

Comment: That is correct .. [OdooInVue](https://www.odooinvue.org/) is not for implementing Vue inside of Odoo ... and I would not recommend trying it. It's for making a stand-alone Vue app that talks to Odoo in the backend.